# Problems with the TF2 learning rate scheduler

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning

I am using the TF2 research object detection API with an EfficientDet D3 model for my training. The optimizer is defined in my `pipeline.config` file like this:

```
optimizer {
  adam_optimizer {
    learning_rate {
      cosine_decay_learning_rate {
        learning_rate_base: 0.08
        total_steps: 300000
        warmup_learning_rate: 0.001
        warmup_steps: 250
      }
    }
  }
  use_moving_average: false
}
```

So I would assume the learning rate would go up to 0.08 until step 250, afterwards it would slowly go down again until end of training at step 30,000 - is that assumption correct?

However, the learning rate chart in Tensorboard looks like this:

[image: Tensorboard Learning Rate Chart]

So the learning rate is sticking to 0.08 after step 250 has been reached.
I tried to let that run for hours - the learning rate won't go down at all.

What I am missing here?

PS: The whole `pipeline.config` file [can be found here](https://gist.github.com/haimat/9a373f7b021bbfd6c69c3e8134fce27c).

Comment: You're saying 30,000 in your question, but you have 300,000 in your pipeline config. With that number of steps, the lr value at the step 555 is still `0.07999979`, close enough to 0.08 to look flat.

Comment: @Lescurel Ohh yes, that may be the issue. Thanks for that, I will check it out with 30.000 steps.

Comment: @Lescurel You were perfectly right - do you want to post that as an answer?

Comment: No, I think this should just be closed because of a Typo.